# Tools needed to get started with Silverlight

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

What tools are required to start silverlight development?  Is VS2008 adequate?

Background: I'm thinking of dipping my toes into silverlight.  I'm tired of the flash dev tools and process, specifically the PITA communicating with a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Studio you're also going to want to get your hands on Expression blend.  Since these products are made by two separate teams (Studio and Blend), you'll find that there are some things that are easier to do in one vs. the other.

I personally use both, going from Blend to handle animations and roughing out, and then back to Studio to do the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to get started with Silverlight:

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

As far as VS2008 is concerned I think You will be needing VS2008 Team Edition .

Comment: Why is Team Edition required?  Thanks.